# How does MATLAB AutoEncoder scale data?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, autoencoder

I found in the documentation of AutroEcnoder that:

> Indicator to rescale the input data, specified as the comma-separated
>   pair consisting of 'ScaleData' and either true or false.
>
> Autoencoders attempt to replicate their input at their output. For it
>   to be possible, the range of the input data must match the range of
>   the transfer function for the decoder. trainAutoencoder automatically
>   scales the training data to this range when training an autoencoder.
>   If the data was scaled while training an autoencoder, the predict,
>   encode, and decode methods also scale the data.

How does MATLAB do this? When I ran a model like this:

```
hiddenSize1 = 1;
autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(tdata, hiddenSize1, 'UseGPU',true);
factor_1 = encode(autoenc1, tdata);
```

I found out the fact that mean of `factor_1` is not 0 and the standard divination of it is not 1. So what is the procedure for standardizing the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
[x,t] = wine_dataset;

autoenc = trainAutoencoder(x, 10, 'EncoderTransferFunction', 'logsig', 'ScaleData', true);

encoded_data1 = encode(autoenc, x);

x_scaled = (x-min(x,[],2))./(max(x,[],2)-min(x,[],2));

encoded_data2 = logsig(autoenc.EncoderWeights * x_scaled + autoenc.EncoderBiases);
```